# ADB Screen Record with Audio

Tags: adb, screencast

I have prototype hardware and an application that produces sound. I would like to use ADB to record, the screen, audio out and audio in, all at the same time. Is there a way to do this?

Note: Because it's prototype hardware and we have our own distro of Android (4.4.2, I think, or thereabouts), I (probably) can't use an app - which is why I'm specifying ADB.

Comment: for reference,  people who have come here through google: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200437/record-tablets-screen-and-audio

Comment: seems audio recording is not possible through adb, as per the post linked above